# Why my app doesn't see any beacons when uploaded to phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I build a mobile app in EvoThings that scans for beacons. But when I upload to PhoneGap Build, the app doesn't scan anything. And there is no plugins on the Phonegap Website.

here is my config.xml file. I just added all the plugins for bluetooth and beacons in hope it will work.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget 
 id="com.sap.beaconsphonegap" 
 version="0.0.1" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
 xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
 <name>BeaconsPhonegap</name>
 <description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
 </description>
 <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
     Apache Cordova Team
 </author>
 <content src="index.html" />
 <plugin name="com.unarin.cordova.beacon" spec="3.2.1" source="pgb" />
 <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetoothle" source="npm" />

 <plugin name="com.megster.cordova.bluetoothserial" spec="0.3.3" source="pgb" />
 <plugin name="com.evothings.ble" spec="1.0.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="com.megster.cordova.ble" spec="0.1.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="eu.mobilion.ibeacon" spec="0.0.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="com.michelbb.cordova.beacon" spec="3.3.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="com.conetix.ibeacon" spec="1.0.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="com.estimote.sdk" spec="1.1.0" source="npm" />
 <plugin name="com.jkhax0r.bluetoothle" spec="1.0.1" source="npm" />
 <access origin="*" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
 <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
 <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
 <platform name="android">
     <allow-intent href="market:*" />
 </platform>
 <platform name="ios">
     <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
     <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
 </platform>
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong in here.

**EDITOR'S NOTE:** This developer has a misconception about how *Phonegap CLI* and *Phonegap Build*. Reading the FAQ listed in the comments will resolve the misconception.

Comment: You have multiple conflicting plugins [Adobe Communities for Phonegap Build](https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build) -- Read this FAQ. It will help [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650  Do you know exactly which plugin I have to use in order to make my app interact with beacons?    When adding plugin in CLI, do I have to add something in config.xml as well or not??   Thanks

Comment: Read the FAQ and you will find out about your misconception - which creates the error - which breaks your build.